# Use double and single quotes in an echo statement

Tags: php, echo

I am struggling to work out how I can use both double and single quotes in an echo statement without breaking open the echo.

For example, I want to create a link that outputs like this:

```
<a href="http:/www.blah.com" class="read-more" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'External Link', 'Buy Link', 'Item name']);">Read this post...</a>
```

However I want to output PHP variables in place of the `href` and as one of the parameters in the `onClick`

The `href` part is easy, I can break open the PHP echo and concat the variable in:

```
echo '<a href="'.$link.'" class="read-more">Read this post...</a>';
```

But i'm stuck when it comes to the parameters inside the onClick, because I can't include them as the use of `'` breaks open my echo:

```
echo '<a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'External Link', 'Buy Link', ''. echo $pattern_name .'']);">Read this post...</a>';
```

So this code above breaks when it gets to the `'trackEvent'` part because the single quotes break it open.

What can I do?

Comment: Escape the nested single quotes: `onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslashes ([escape characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Programming_and_data_formats)) are your best friend:

```
echo '<a href="'.the_permalink().'" class="read-more" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'External Link\', \'Buy Link\', \''. $pattern_name .'\']);">Read this post...</a>';
```

Comment: Just to note.. This is escaping.. Incase any people want to google it.. Backslashes can mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, but personally i find it ugly code when using something like echo '

I would suggest something more along these lines (escaping)

```
$pattern_name = "something";
$linkhref = someFunction();
echo "<a href='{$linkhref}' class='read-more' onclick='_gaq.push([\"_trackEvent\", \"External Link\", \"Buy Link\", \"{$pattern_name}\"]);'>Read this post...</a>";
```

Of this

```
$pattern_name = "something";
echo "<a href='".someFunction()."' class='read-more' onclick='_gaq.push([\"_trackEvent\", \"External Link\", \"Buy Link\", \"{$pattern_name}\"]);'>Read this post...</a>";
```

Just a personal preference

Results in...

```
<a href='index.php' class='read-more' onclick='_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "External Link", "Buy Link", "something"]);'>Read this post...</a>
```

Using complex (curly) syntax, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex